# Is it mandatory to dismiss a view when it is presented in ios?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am working on iPad App.

Here I am having different views with different orientations. Among them I am PRESENTING a view on clicking button.

While I am DISMISSING that view i am facing orientation problem.

So, to clear that issue i changed the rootviewcontroller after pressing done button where it was dismissed previously.

By doing this my issue was cleared and now not facing any orientation issue.

But what my doubt is does it reaches Apple standards?

Should we dismiss the view if it was presented? Or

should I load the view with any animation effect? Good suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Not always but in your case yes! you can handel orientation problems by little effort but loading one viewController unnecessarily, as you said it's already in memory is not a good approach.

Comment: but it is in ARC @rptwsthi

Comment: Still, I think view hierarchy will be abused by this method.